# Query Exception with subgraph after updating to Spring Data JPA 2.3.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

An entity is annotated with the following entity graph annotation:

```
 @NamedEntityGraphs({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "searchItem",
                attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("address"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("owner"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("logEntries"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "address", subgraph = "address")
                },
                subgraphs = {
                        @NamedSubgraph(name = "address", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("location")),
                        @NamedSubgraph(name = "address", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("type")),
                        @NamedSubgraph(name = "address", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("properties"))
                })
})
```

This entity graph is used in a repository method for this entity:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "searchItem")
Set<Entity> findAll(Specification<Entity> spec, Sort sort);
```

Everything used to work fine, but after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.4.3 (which includes Spring Data JPA 2.4.3) it stopped working. Multiple test cases threw the following exception when calling the repository function:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties [...]
```

However, if I delete the following line in the entity graph, the tests work flawlessly.

```
 @NamedAttributeNode(value = "address", subgraph = "address")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please try to downgrade the Hibernate version to the previous version while still using the newer Spring Data JPA version to see if this might be Hibernate related.

Comment: I've already tried that. However, it didn't solve the problem. I was able to trace it down to the new Spring Data JPA version.

Comment: In that case you should probably create a bug ticket in their issue tracker.

Comment: Could you add your `Entity` code with joining here?